# Group By and pagination not working togather laravel

Tags: php, laravel, group-by, pagination

```php
$campaigns = Campaign::orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(2)->groupBy('offer_id');
```

results returning 2 rows but no pagination links.

Comment: what would you be expecting `groupBy` to be doing for you? the call to `paginate` returns your Paginator, calling a Collection method on it then returns a Collection not a Paginator

Answer (score 1):

You should use `groupBy` first then paginate in Laravel as its chaining of method calling your last method will be given result as two records without pagination

```php
Campaign::orderBy('id','DESC')->groupBy('offer_id')->paginate(2);
```

Comment: In this case pagination is working but not groupby